# Is there a way to provide a Java Comparator to a Spark ReduceByKey function?

Tags: apache-spark

I have `JavaPairRDD<KeyClass, ValueClass> rdd` where my `KeyClass` has several fields.

I would like to reduceByKey based on only a subset of fields in my `KeyClass`.  I'm doing it by mapping the RDD:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<KeyClass, ValueClass>> readyForReduce = rdd.MapToPair(addKey());
```

I know I can pass in a partitioner but that just determines the partition for the record not how it is reduced.

Also I do not want to override the hash method of the KeyClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have listed all the possible solutions in the *can't-do* list afaik. However, using `keyBy` will lead to a code that is closer to what you want to achieve. Note that you will still end up with a pair `RDD`.

```
val readyToReduce = rdd.keyBy{case (k, v) => pickKeysYouWant(k)}
```

Example:

```
scala>  val a = sc.parallelize(List(((1, "adam"), "adams_info"), ((2, "bob"), "bobs_info")))

scala> a.collect.map(println)

scala> val readyToReduce = a.keyBy{case (key, value) => key._2}

scala> readyToReduce.collect.map(println)
(adam,((1,adam),adams_info))
(bob,((2,bob),bobs_info))
```